# R programming ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am working with `mpg` dataset from the `ggplot2` package. I am stuck with this question:

Plot the median of `cty` and `hwy` variables against type of fuel (bivariate bar plot). Arrange both x axes in either ascending or descending order.

I have just plotted the bargraph for the fuel but wasnt able to plot the median of `cty` and `hwy`. Here is my code:

```
libray(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(fl)))+
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using facetting may look like so. I simply computed the medians using `group_by` + `summarise_at`. Next I order the factor `fl` by `cty` (gives the same order as ordering by `hwy`). Finally I convert the df to long format and plot. You can alos drop the facet and have both vars in one plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  group_by(fl) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(cty, hwy), median) %>%
  mutate(fl = forcats::fct_reorder(fl, cty)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-fl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(fl), value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ name) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>